# MS SQL - Best way to implement loop

Tags: sql, sql-server, optimization, stored-procedures

Existing Objects and content

There is a table named history_master which records everytime a particular table named master is updated. It is like a history of master table. master table contains latest data only

To give an example of contents

master table

```
| id | item no| valid from | valid till | 
| 1  | 1      | 2012-12-25 | 2012-12-31 | 
| 2  | 1      | 2013-01-01 | 2013-04-30 |
| 3  | 2      | 2013-01-10 | 2013-12-31 |
```

history_master looks like

```
| id | item no | valid from | valid till | update date |
| 1  |   1     | 2012-01-01 | 2012-06-30 | 2012-02-01  |
| 2  |   1     | 2012-07-01 | 2012-12-31 | 2012-02-01  |
| 3  |   1     | 2012-01-01 | 2012-06-30 | 2012-05-01  |
| 4  |   1     | 2012-07-01 | 2012-11-30 | 2012-05-01  |
| 5  |   1     | 2012-12-01 | 2012-12-31 | 2012-05-01  |
| 6  |   1     | 2012-07-01 | 2012-11-30 | 2012-08-01  |
| 7  |   1     | 2012-12-01 | 2012-12-24 | 2012-08-01  |
| 8  |   1     | 2012-12-25 | 2012-12-31 | 2012-08-01  |
```

Task at hand : write a stored procedure that gets all available data for an item from history retaining latest data i.e. the result should look like

```
| item no | valid from | valid till | history_id |
|   1     | 2012-12-25 | 2012-12-31 | 8          |
|   1     | 2012-12-01 | 2012-12-24 | 7          |
|   1     | 2012-07-01 | 2012-11-30 | 6          |
|   1     | 2012-01-01 | 2012-06-30 | 3          |
```

The logic that I thought of is to determine the batches from history table. For e.g. records with update date 2012-08-01 will have batch = 3, with 2012-05-01 will have batch = 2 and last with batch = 1

Starting with latest (3) to oldest (1) iterate through all batches, compare date ranges and determine resultant keeping in mind that data of latest set will always bear priority.

The only way to implementation I can think of is WHILE LOOP and I am not sure if it is the best way.

The history master contains 10155734 records as of now. Please suggest

Comment: Why do you need a stored procedure. This should be solveable with a single SQL statement.

Comment: what is the relation beetween the two tables? I don't see anything like master_id in history_master, and item_id isn't unique.

Comment: SQL is a language oriented around *sets* - you construct queries that say how the input sets should be processed, and the server works out how best to achieve this and produce an output set. Loops should generally be avoided. and 10 million rows isn't huge.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name How ?

Comment: @Dutow There is no foreign key constraint between the two tables. item_no is not unique because it is not the primary key. It is an object for which we have multiple date ranges. Only latest one in master and all arrived till date in history_master

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever yes, I understand. that is why the question. I tried to see how I could convert some to CTE for e.g. But there are tasks like date comparison to determine resultant interval sets which I am not able to fit in this approach

Comment: But in your example, the first two rows in master have both item_no 1, and in your example output only id=1 shown, id=2 not.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to put the update dates into a temporary table like this

```
select distinct [update date], identity(int, 1,1) history_id 
into #updatedates
order by [update date]
```

this gives you a table like this

```
update date history_id
2012-08-01  1
2012-09-01  2
2012-10-01  3
```

then join that with your original table to get your result

```
select mh.[item no], mh.[vaild from], mh.[valid to], u.history_id
from master_history mh join #updatedates u on mh.[update date] = u.[update date]
```